# Language Problem with Audio System on 2007 Toyota Raum

Tags: audio

Please let me know who the manufacturers of HDD NH3T-W56 Audio System are. This is the system fitted on my 2007 Toyota Raum and I intend to approach them for translation of the Japanese instructions therein. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This website called [Nengun](http://www.nengun.com/toyota/toyota-genuine-hdd-navigation-nh3t-w56-119269) shows the same model `NH3T-W56` (but the web site says "Toyota genuine". If that's true you should've asked Toyota for a help so I don't know if this web site is right).

Comment: Is downvoting w/o leaving any reason a custom on this forum (if so how can I improve my future behavior) ?

Comment: Not sure why your answers was down-voted, seems like it's helpful to me. While Dobey's answer could answer every question on the site but wouldn't be very helpful

Comment: The voting system should identify the voter, if only to identify the integrity of the person voting.

Comment: This answer is basically exactly the same as mine. "I did a Google search for you, and the result says to contact Toyota."

Comment: @dobey Even so, how can one tell your answer was/is based on a fact if you don't cite any reference? To the least, you don't need to denounce another post that provides more info (with a reference to external resources) even if the core message is the same as yours IMO.

Answer (score 0):

You should contact Toyota to get support for OEM installed equipment in a Toyota.